# jQuery passing params to MVC Controller. Why are my params empty?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm converting a Web Forms app to MVC.

**I have a js method that calls a Controller action method (below)**

`function GetUsers(pageNum) {
    var sortTh = $('thead .sort', document.getElementById('usersTable'));
    var sortCol = sortTh.find('a').attr('rel');`

```
// { } is declarative shorthand for new Object().
var userRequest = {};
userRequest.pageNum = pageNum;
userRequest.pageSize = 10; //records per page
userRequest.sortType = (sortTh.hasClass('ascending')) ? 'ascending' : 'descending';
userRequest.sortColumn = sortCol;
//alert(userRequest.sortType + " - " + sortCol);
// Create a data transfer object (DTO) with the proper structure.
var DTO = { 'userRequest': userRequest };

//Ajax
var urlMethod = "/Users/GetUsers";  //"../WebServices/ws_Users.asmx/GetUsers";
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(DTO);
SendAjax(urlMethod, jsonData, ReturnGetUsers, 'get');
```

}

**This code works, you can even see the Post in Firebug.**

{"userRequest":"pageNum":1,"pageSize":10,"sortType":"descending","sortColumn":"LastLoginDate"}}

`[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetUsers(UsersModels.GetUserRequest userRequest)
{`

```
//Talk to Web Service
var wsUsers = new WS_Users();
var userList = wsUsers.GetUsers(userRequest);

return Json(userList);
```

}

**I set a breakpoint in the above and all my parameters are empty? WHY oh why?**

Here's the model:

`public class GetUserRequest
{
    public int pageNum;
    public int pageSize;
    public string sortType;
    public string sortColumn;
}`

Help!

Comment: What is SendAjax and what should its arguments be? What is ReturnGetUsers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I wonder if the members of GetUserRequest need to be public properties rather than public fields?

Comment: That's it!!! changed to properties and it works! In Web Forms it's fine with them being fields. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SendAjax(urlMethod, jsonData, ReturnGetUsers, 'get');
```

I don't know what goes on in that SendAjax code but that "get" looks like it should be a "post" to me

Answer (score 0):

your GetUserRequest model should be like this

```
public class GetUserRequest { 
  public int pageNum {get;set;}
  public int pageSize {get;set;}
  public string sortType {get;set;}
  public string sortColumn{ get;set;}
}
```